# dpkg install with apt-get autoremove

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, dpkg, dependencies

OS: Debian 8

I wanted to install PepperFlash, which is non-free.  I don't anticipate installing many non-free packages, so instead of modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list` and downloading from the non-free repository, I decided to install this manually using dpkg with the packaged obtained from [here](http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/p/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/).  This required the dependency `binutils`, which I installed via `apt-get install -f`.

Now as test, I immediately ran

`apt-get remove pepperflashplugin-nonfree`

followed by

`apt-get autoremove`

Yet `binutils`, the newly added dependency, was not removed.

Questions:

1. Why didn't the dependency `binutils` get removed?  Is it because it replaced another installed package, and therefore became a dependency of something else?
2. How do I remove dependencies of manually installed programs via dpkg?